# PostGIS: unable to import GeoJSON data (selected attributes) to PostgreSQL database using ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson, ogr2ogr, select

I downloaded sample `OSM` data of my area of interest via [Overpass-turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) as `my_map.geojson`. I am trying to import this `geojson` file to my `PostgreSQL 10 (Windows 8 x64 machine)` database using `ogr2ogr` (QGIS OSGeo CMD tool). The following command imports entire `my_map.geojson` without errors.

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=localhost user=my_user dbname=my_db password=my_pw" -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom -lco FID=gid -nln my_tbl path_to_my_map.geojson
```

However, when I try to import selected attributes using following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=localhost user=my_user dbname=my_db password=my_pw" -select 'name,highway,oneway,surface' -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom -lco FID=gid -nln my_tbl path_to_my_map.geojson
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 1: Field ''name' not found in source layer.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer map (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

Any idea why `-select` flag of `ogr2ogr` throws error?

**Update:**

The output of:

```
ogrinfo -al -so path_to_my_map.geojson
```

is,

```
Layer name: my_map
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 28
..
..
id: String (0.0)
@id: String (0.0)
highway: String (0.0)
name: String (0.0)
surface: String (0.0)
```

Comment: Which fields GDAL finds with `ogrinfo -al -so path_to_my_map.geojson`?

Comment: Just updated the question with the output of above command, thank you.

Comment: don't enclose the column list with `'`

Comment: Care to post your comment as solution? it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters passed to `ogr2ogr` flags are themselves parsed as string literals (and/or parsed to numeric types if needed); **they don't require string enclosing (`'` or `"`)**, rather, consider them always getting enclosed implicitly.

To explain the behavior:

- `-select col1, col2` implicitly translates to `"col1", "col2"`

  - thus `-select 'col1', 'col2'` will translate to `"'col1'", "'col2'"`
    or `-select 'col1, col2'` to `"'col1", "col2'"`, as in your case
  - non-standard column names, however, need string enclosing, just as referring to them in a SQL client would: `-select "c0l!", col2`

**Notes:**

- flags like `-sql` expect an *arbitrary query string* as parameter to be passed and interpreted to the SQL backend; thus you need to pass the parameter with string enclosing

  - `-sql "SELECT * FROM my_table"`
- in e.g. the `-where` flag you need to add string enclosing if you want to filter e.g. a text column, like `-where name='Peter'`, but `-where number=1`